# Orthogonality of pseudo random basis functions

Tags: signal-analysis

I was reading about Matching Pursuit and it struck me that you might use a dictionary simply consisting of uniformly distributed bipolar pseudo random vectors, instead of, say, Gabor atoms or windowed sinusoids.

Then I thought about orthogonality. Given a set of vectors, what would be one way to measure their orthogonality? We would ideally like to see the inner products [ V_i V_j ] vanishing for i != j. How do we quantify departure from this ideal? Furthermore, what level of orthogonality would we expect given a set of N uniformly distributed pseudo random vectors?

Comment: Not sure how you relate matching pursuit methods to orthogonality. The point of the pursuit is that your dictionary is overcomplete and therefore not an orthogonal set.

Comment: Yes, I realize that the dictionary in Matching Pursuit is overcomplete. But wouldn't we expect a "more orthogonal" dictionary to better match any signal, in the sense that the residual would be smaller?

Comment: It's much more difficult to guarantee completeness than (approximate) orthogonality. Good random sequences don't correlate with each other, so they're close to orthogonal. The problem arises if you want to have enough such sequences to span the space and at the same time guarantee orthogonality. You'll start to span all possible subspaces with non-orthogonal sequences before you can cover the entire space, so that completeness will ruin your orthogonality condition. Also, what kind of result do you expect from a random dictionary?

Comment: Ok, I see. Thank you for your input. Anyway, what kind of result? Something sonically interesting. I'm thinking of using this as a sound effect. Just how important is (over)completeness to resynthesis, for instance. You seem to be in the know, can you point me to "the literature"?

Comment: How would resynthesis affect the sound? Are you planning on manipulating the expansion coefficients? If yes, then practically any change will just add noise to your result.

Comment: No, I'm not planning on modulating the coefficients. The effect parameters would be quantization level (number of bits per coefficient), size of dictionary and length of dictionary atoms. I was thinking of some kind of overlap-add scheme. Are you sure I could model this as simply additive noise?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30358/discussion-between-emanuel-landeholm-and-jazzmaniac).

Comment: Let's put it like that: It's extremely unlikely to find a coefficient configuration that does not result in noise. Other decomposition families prefer certain features that are sparsely represented. Only your sparse representations are all noise. So you will get noise with an overwhelming probability for any change of the coefficients. And what's more, the coefficients will do an extremely poor job at encoding your signal with a high signal to noise ratio.